# Where to learn Euclidean geometry in-depth?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I am interested in Euclidean geometry and using compass and rulers to do constructions. I took geometry in high school but I feel like it didn't go in-depth enough. Where can I learn this online? I am interested in  as a hobby.

Comment: There are two software things I know, one is called the Geometer's Sketchpad, the other is called GeoGebra, I think. One is probably free. Both are popular with teachers, there should be plenty of lessons online to work out.

Comment: Perhaps [these Construction Worksheets at Math Open Reference](http://www.mathopenref.com/worksheetlist.html) will be useful.

Comment: I recommend learning field theory first - then you'll be able to prove what you can't construct using straightedge and compass. But that's just my humble opinion.

Comment: Perhaps Hilbert's [Geometry and the Imagination](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Imagination-CHEL-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821819984#reader_0821819984) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

There are two more recent books I like:

- Stillwell's "The Four Pillars of Geometry"
- Hartshorne's "Geometry: Euclid and beyond"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest browsing the forums and resources at [Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com). As for books, Coxeter's Geometry Revisited is excellent.